# How to use md-select using array data?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material, javascript-framework, angular-controller

I am using angularjs and angular material to design my web page. I am unable to show the values of option present in an array.

My `index.html`

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
  <label>Level</label>
  {{levels|json}}
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="level in levels"> {{level.name}}</li><!--this is working-->
  </ul>
  <md-select ng-model="news.level">
       <md-option ng-repeat="level in levels"ng-value="level.name">
         {{level.name}}
        </md-option><!--this is not working-->
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

And in the controller I have

```
$scope.levels=['Level one', 'Level two','Level Three'];
```

Please help what could possibly be wrong and also let me know of any suggestion to this problem.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Try to add missing space before `ng-value="level.name"` in here `<md-option ng-repeat="level in levels"ng-value="level.name">` and also you're missing `name` property in your levels object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/bwgyOQ?editors=1010#0)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>Level</label>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="level in levels"> {{level.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <md-select ng-model="news.level">
      <md-option ng-repeat="level in levels" ng-value="level.name">
        {{level.name}}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache', 'ngDialog'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.levels = [{name:'Level one'}, {name:'Level two'}, {name:'Level Three'}];
});
```

Comment: I think a better solution would be to explain why OP code didn't work in the first place. Without explanation is going to get you downvote for sure.

Comment: @Samundra You don't think looking at the value of `$scope.levels` is enough? I assume the OP knows AngularJS to a certain level.

Comment: thanks @camden_kid I got it. and now I know what was wrong.

Comment: Yeah noticed it a bit later, OP missed `name` property. I think it's SO's policy to have explanation. And some people have very outrageous tendency to downvote to answers without descriptive answers, have faced many times before and so sharing opinion.

Comment: @Samundra Understood. Thank you.